Term for a single piece of jargon
I believe there’s a three-word phrase that means “a specific piece of jargon, used in a different sense than it’s normal meaning.” It’s something like word of practice or word of field. It feels more formal than jargon. I think it specifically means a word that has an ordinary meaning that is being disregarded, not just any technical word.

Hardness here is a ____ of ____; in geology it specifically refers to measuring which minerals can scratch which other minerals.
End of day is a _____ of _____ at [company]; it always refers to 4pm Eastern Time when the stock market closes.

It might be a French loanphrase—my brain is supplying me with nom de plume, which obviously isn’t correct.
My best phrase right now is “technical word/phrase” (too general) or just describing it as “used in the domain-specific sense”.
(Searching for “jargon synonyms” doesn’t get me there, “singular jargon” doesn’t help, and “technical word synonyms" just gives synonyms for technical.)

You're aware that you can just use jargon as with any uncountable noun? ".. is jargon for 4pm".  Secondly note that the two examples you give are not, I would say, jargon - jargon is generally pejorative, something like saying "slang"; jargon is pointless shibboleth-like insider slang.

One such phrase is term of art:

term of art noun
(also word of art (now rare))
A word or phrase used in a precise sense in a particular subject or field; a technical term.
[OED]


Think that's it. Thank you!

Yes, and a streamlined answer at its best.

... involving a stipulative definition.

In fact, the term of art is "term of art". ;)

Dictionary.com {based on the Random House Unabridged Dictionary} has the more detailed definition: <<term of art
[noun]:
a word or phrase that has a specific or precise meaning within a given discipline or field and might have a different meaning in common usage ... >> One may think of 'similar' and 'integral' in maths.

Technical term is common. Its Latin equivalent terminus technicus is also valid.
Technical term is plainer language than term of art without being less accurate, which is why I would prefer it, especially in international environments. Both the English term and the Latin one also have entries in Wiktionary.

The accepted answer includes this.

@EdwinAshworth As an explanation, not as a suggestion.

'Technical term' is given in the dictionary you quote as a descriptive definition, not a headword.

@EdwinAshworth Well, it is given as the translation and thus arguably as the English equivalent. Wiktionary has both. Be that as it may: It has no import on my suggestion. I think indeed that technical term is the best suggestion, for the reasons given.

Yes; Wiktionary licenses the term 'technical term' (OED, I believe it is, doesn't claim it to be more than say a loose collocation or even free combination. Give credit to Andrew Leach, and I'll upvote.

@Fattie The answer here does not quote a definition of 'technical term' showing that it is an established term; dictionary definitions may use free combinations as well as compounds (recognised fixed terms). If the Wiktionary definition which licenses (by listing) 'technical term' is included, which it is not in Andrew Leach's answer, this becomes a valid separate answer.

Edwin you said "The accepted answer includes this." (That's your comment, and your comment is what I was complaining about.)  It's a bit churlish of you to say that, because, the accepted answer merely "includes" the phrase in a quote.  The accepted answer does not suggest this answer.  (I feel, fwiw, that this answer is slightly better than the accepted answer.)  that's all!  Storm in a teacup!

Yeah, technical term is a good phrase as well. I was specifically looking for term of art but it's a good reminder that term of art might be itself confusing

Because the original poster had the recollection that there might be a French one, I think it is worth contributing a Latin one for their peace of mind: terminus technicus.
Wiktionary has this entry:

terminus technicus
English
Etymology
Latin terminus technicus.
Noun
terminus technicus
A technical term, a term of art.

The online Oxford English Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionary and Merriam-Webster do not contain this phrase.

Yes, there are enough examples on the internet to justify this as a loan word (or loan phrase for those who don't accept open compounds). Plural termini technici. But if 'term of art' is very formal, this is rarefied.

That sounds vaguely filthy, for some reason.

@Fattie Only to a dirty mind ;-).
